# 403 forbidden when retrieve all users from Azure AD using Graph API

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I get a 403 Forbidden response from Azure AD when trying to get all users using the Graph API:

```
    public static async Task<string> AppAuthenticationAsync()
    {
        var tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        var resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
        var clientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        var secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppKey"];

        var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}";
        var authContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var credentials = new ClientCredential(clientID, secret);
        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credentials);

        return authResult.AccessToken;
    }

    public static async Task<string[]> GetUsersListAsync(HttpClient client)
    {
        var payload = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(payload);
        var users = from g in obj["value"]
                               select g["displayName"].Value<string>();

        return users.ToArray();
    }
```

And below is the code, which use in my controller to get the result

```
   var token = await AppAuthenticationAsync();
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
       var users = await GetUsersListAsync(client);
       lstADUsers = users.ToList();
   }
```

The client registered in Azure AD has all the permissions:

[image]

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have given delegated permissions, but call the API with client credentials.

Give your app application permissions on the API and you'll be able to call it.
Delegated permissions only apply when you make calls on behalf of a user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the thing is, same web application works fine with another Azure AD application where I have provided only delegated permissions. And even the delegated permissions are same.

Comment: Something else must different, it simply isn't possible to use Delegated scopes with the Client Credentials OAuth Grant.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for your suggestion, but I have already spent almost 2-4 hours validating both the Azure AD applications, and trust me, settings for both the applications are same. Meanwhile let me try to give application permissions and check what happens.

Comment: Settings are same but is the code running in the apps the same?